# Not able to get content of S3 file uploaded by SES with non-root user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I am using SES for receiving emails for my domain and then send content to S3 using the S3 action of SES. 
As I am a non-root user of the s3 bucket, So not able to access files uploaded by SES because ownership is changed.
Any idea how to get rid of it.

Comment: Is the message encrypted? How are you accessing the file? What are the IAM policies? does it have a Bucket policy?

Comment: If your user has permission to read objects from the bucket, it should make no difference whether it is the root user or not.  On the other hand, if your user is from a different AWS account, you won't be able to access these objects cross-account, even with read permission on the bucket. Please clarify your situation.

Comment: The message is not encrypted and yes I have permissions to read bucket.

Comment: Yes @Michael-sqlbot bucket is cross-account,  Any way out to access?